# Not seeing Ruby on Rails debugging console in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I do a raise in my controller#create as follows:

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :request_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    raise
    @request = Request.new(request_params)
    if @request.save
      RequestMailer.received_request(@request).deliver_now
      flash.now[:success] = {message: t(".success"), body: ""}
      @request = Request.new
      respond_to do |format|
        format.turbo_stream
      end
    else
      flash.now[:error] = {message: t(".error"), body: @request.errors.full_messages.join(", ")}
      render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace(:flash_messages, partial: "shared/flash_messages")
    end
  end

  private

  def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :subject, :message, :date)
  end
end
```

Im not able to see the browser console with that breakpoint in browser.
I get the error in my local console only, not being able to properly debug:

```
web    | Started POST "/requests" for ::1 at 2023-02-20 12:52:10 -0600
web    | Processing by RequestsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
web    |   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "request"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "subject"=>"", "email"=>"", "message"=>"", "date"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
web    | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 954)
web    | 
web    | 
web    |   
web    | RuntimeError ():
web    |   
web    | app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

I have also set `all_requests_local = true` to true in development.rb

Comment: Can you please more fully describe the expected behavior? My expectation based on your description is that you should see what you see here. Are you expecting something like [debug](https://github.com/ruby/debug) to be invoked? Are you expecting something like [`binding.irb`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/Binding.html#method-i-irb) to be invoked?

Comment: When I place: "raise" in any view. I will see a debugging console in browser.
But when I try doing it from a controller I cannot see this error screen in localhost:3000

Yes, I can use a debugger such as pry-byebug.
But this type of errors in browser help a lot

Comment: Are you using a third-party library to do this? The behavior you describe not documented in [Debugging Rails Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) nor in the [web-console gem](https://github.com/rails/web-console).

Comment: Thanks I just post an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use binding.pry to stop the program in console.
Im debugging well now.

If binding.pry prompt is not appearing, do the next:
Use tmux to run the next process in different terminals:

- watch: css
- watch: web

Or simply open 2 terminals in one run `rails s` and in the other run `bin/rails tailwindcss:watch` (or your any compiler you are using like webpack)

Seems that having the css and web was hiding `binding.pry prompt`.